# Rails - Generate email address when one doesn't exist with Omniauth integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, omniauth, rails-postgresql

I am working with omniauth with `Rails` and trying to get twitter, facebook and google hooked up for authentication but keep running into this error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_users_on_email"
DETAIL:  Key (email)=() already exists.
```

Here is my Authentication Controller:

```
class AuthorizationsController < ApplicationController


      def create
        authentication = Authorization.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth['provider'], auth['uid'])

        if authentication
          flash[:notice] = "Signed In Successfully"
          sign_in authentication.user, event: :authentication
          redirect_to root_path
        else
          athlete = Athlete.new
          athlete.apply_omniauth(auth)

          debugger

          if athlete.save(validate: false)
            flash[:notice] = "Account created and signed in successfully"
            sign_in athlete, event: :authentication
            redirect_to finalize_profile_path
          else
            flash[:error] = "An error has occurred. Please try again."
            redirect_to root_path
          end
        end
      end

      def failure
        render json: params.to_json
      end

      private

        def auth
          request.env["omniauth.auth"]
        end

        def resource(user_type)
          user_type.downcase.to_sym
        end

    end
```

I think what is happening is that when the Athlete is created it is creating one with a blank email address and the unique key is failing... how could I get around this? I think I know how to fix this for Google integration but since Twitter doesn't return an email, this issue will not resolve itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I was able to get it working:

```
class AuthorizationsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    authentication = Authorization.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth['provider'], auth['uid'])

    if authentication
      flash[:notice] = "Signed In Successfully"
      sign_in authentication.user, event: :authentication
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      athlete = Athlete.new(email: generate_auth_email(params[:provider]) )
      athlete.apply_omniauth(auth)

      debugger

      if athlete.save(validate: false)
        flash[:notice] = "Account created and signed in successfully"
        sign_in athlete, event: :authentication
        redirect_to finalize_profile_path
      else
        flash[:error] = "An error has occurred. Please try again."
        redirect_to root_path
      end
    end
  end

  def failure
    render json: params.to_json
  end

  private

    def auth
      request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    end

    def resource(user_type)
      user_type.downcase.to_sym
    end

    def generate_auth_email(provider)
      return auth.info.try(:email) unless provider == "twitter"
      return "#{auth.uid}@twitter.com" if provider == "twitter"
    end

end
```

I create an email using the twitter uid with twitter.com being the domain since twitter does not return an email address

Hope this helps someone in the future

Comment: That's nice. But way more complicated than needbe. You could've just done something like: ` user.email = auth.info.email = "#{auth.uid}@twitter.com" `